# OverflowError: repeated string is too long

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script for when I'm using my radio. When trying to calculate wavelength, I get an OverflowError. Is it possible to overcome this problem?

Here is my code:

```
while 1:
cmd = input("Enter command: ")
if cmd == 'wavelength':
    freq = input("Enter frequency (mHz): ") * 10**6 
    wl = freq * 299792458
    print (wl)
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter command: wavelength
Enter frequency (mHz): 33
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ross/Desktop/Programming/Python/Radio/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    wl = freq * 299792458
OverflowError: repeated string is too long
```

Comment: `wl = freq * 299792458` should probably be `wl = int(freq) * 299792458`

Comment: it could also be `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
if cmd == 'wavelength':
    freq = input("Enter frequency (mHz): ") * 10**6 
    wl = freq * 299792458
    print (wl)
```

has not just one problem, it has two problems

1. The `input` function returns a string of characters, that you concatenate to itself a million times, say "107.6107.6107.6 ... 107.6", just one million times.
   You want to convert your response to a floating point nuber, using `float`, *before* multiplying it by 10**6

   ```
   freq = float(input("Enter frequency (mHz): ")) * 10**6
   ```
2. The wavelength calculation is wrong
   Example dimensional analysis: `[L] != (1/[T]) * [L]/[T] = [L]/[T]^2`

   ```
   wl = c/freq
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3.x, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string object.

If you want to number multiplication, convert the return value of the string to numerical value.

```
freq = int(input("Enter frequency (mHz): ")) * 10**6
```

or

```
freq = float(input("Enter frequency (mHz): ")) * 10**6
```

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying a string:

```
input("Enter frequency (mHz): ") * 10**6
wl = freq * 299792458
```

You probably meant:

```
freq = int(input("Enter frequency (mHz): ")) * 10**6
wl = freq * 299792458
```